# Using nested helper functions while building a class

Tags: python, static-methods, class-method, nested-function

I want to build a class which is merely a wrapper for some data.  This is the basic idea:

```
class Fruits:
    fruits = [ 'apple', 'orange', 'cherry' ]
```

My fruits aren’t strings, though, but classes defined earlier:

```
class Apple: pass
class Orange: pass
class Cherry: pass

class Fruits:
    fruits = [ Apple(), Orange(), Cherry() ]
```

My fruit classes are a bit more complex, though:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Apple:
    color: str
    size: float
    price: float
```

Because my fruit-classes are quite complex, I need some helper functions to avoid massive code-doubling while calling the constructors:

```
class Fruits:

    @staticmethod
    def green_apple(size, price_factor=2.5):
        return Apple(color='green', size=size, price=size * price_factor)

    fruits = [ green_apple(3), green_apple(3, price_factor=1.2) ]
```

This far this works with static methods.

Now I would like to have one more layer of abstraction:

```
class Fruits:

    @staticmethod
    def green_apple(size, price_factor=2.5):
        return Apple(color='green', size=size, price=size * price_factor)

    @staticmethod
    def cheap_green_apple(size):
        return green_apple(size, price_factor=1.2)
        # alternative spelling:
        # return Fruits.green_apple(size, price_factor=1.2)

    fruits = [ green_apple(3), cheap_green_apple(3) ]
```

I did not find any way to achieve this yet.  I understand why this is a problem:  The second static method cannot call the first one before the class exists, and the class cannot exist before the `fruits` field hasn’t been built.  There is no logical reason why one static method cannot call another one before the class exists, though.  The methods are just scoped inside the class, they don’t use anything of the class; hence the building of the field `fruits` still works in the example one above.

The methods shall be wrapped in the wrapper class `Fruits` as users of this class are supposed to also use them.  Putting them before the class (and repeating them within) would be an ugly solution, but it would clutter the outer scope, therefore I would like to avoid that.

So my question is not why this happens.  I am asking for clever solutions to achieve what I want:  Several fruit-classes (`Apple`, etc.) and a single wrapper class (`Fruits`) for providing all fruits in my scenario without cluttering the outer scope, while using a nested set of helper functions within the wrapper class.

Is there an option to achieve this?  I tried several variants with static and class methods, but nothing worked yet.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a case for a factory pattern.

An easy solution is to remove your object creation from the Fruits data holder and put it into a dedicated class, a factory.

A possible (quickly written) solution could be:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Apple:
    color: str
    size: float
    price: float


class FruitFactory:
    @staticmethod
    def green_apple(size, price_factor=2.5):
        return Apple(color="green", size=size, price=price_factor)

class Fruits:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fruits = [FruitFactory.green_apple(1)]
    

fruits = Fruits()
print(fruits.fruits)
```

Comment: My main reason to not do it like this is that my users then are forced to know of the `FruitFactory` as well because they are supposed to use the helper functions as well.  I want them to import one thing only: `Fruits` (which btw, is never instantiated, I only use the class, not instances of it).

Comment: @Alfe I wonder why you want this. If your users do know about one class, why not about the other ? What is the point ? As long as you document it well, there should be no problem.

Comment: My reason is purely the wish to avoid any unnecessary clutter of the name space.  Also, it’s not intuitive for the user why he should use two different classes for this simple case.  Me, as a user of libraries, bug such things.  Libraries should be as clear as possible to avoid any useless cognitive load.